# How to identfy whether multiple records available in a table?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

> i have a table Subscription,occupant,Address.I need to find out wether multiple address and occupant availble for a subscription.
>
> in quick index for subscription i have the following details
>
> ```
>    flags   index name         st area  cnt field name
>             addressoccupant     999      2  + Addressid
>                                         + Occupantid
>
>     pu    subscription       999      1 + subscriptionid
> ```
>
> Address table - addressid is primary unique
>   Occupant table -Occupantid is primnary unique
>
> when i query i can't find any multiple address and occupant for a subscription but i need to   make sure wether it can have multiple address and occupant for a subscritpion.

Please let me know how to find this.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of a query that you think might return multiple results.  I've thrown something together in my example below but that might not be quite what you are asking about.

Comment: By seeing the index information could we confirm whether a subscription can have multiple address or occupant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given those indexes it is certainly possible that you could have multiple subscription records for any given addressId or occupantId.

The "addressoccupant" index is not unique and even if it was it would only be unique on the combination of addressId and occupantId fields.

To prevent duplicates you would need to have a unique index defined for each of those fields.  Similar to the "subscription" index but without the "primary" attribute.

That would prevent duplicates but, in the real world, people (who presumably map to "occupants") often have multiple addresses and addresses often have multiple people living in them.  The combination of addressId and occupantId could reasonably be unique but you might not be happy making the individual fields unique -- a lot depends on your application and the actual data.

(You should probably get help from this system's "data architect" if there is such a person.)

As is you can use the AMBIGUOUS keyword to determine if a query returns multiple records:

```
find subscription no-lock where addressid = 34 no-error.  /* "34" is just a made up example... */
if available subscription then
  message "found one!".
 else if ambiguous subscription then
  message "more than 1 :(".
 else
  message "no records".
```